# XSL to make all leaf nodes 'starting with small-letter' tag attributes

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to do an XSL transformation which would convert all leaf-tags starting with small letter '[a-z]' into the parent tag's attribute. Everything works fine till a leaf tags comes really down in the tag order. e.g.

Please refer to the xml below. The 'sessionId' tag is skipped by the transformation because it is placed at the end; however the transformation would work properly if I place it before 'PaginationData' tag.

Q. Could the XSL be corrected such that it doesn't consider tag ordering.

Q. Could someone please explain why tag order like 'sessionId' tag, problem exists?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="Carz.com">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getCarValuedAvail>
        <CarValuedAvailRQ>
            <PaginationData>
                <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                <itemsPerPage/>
            </PaginationData>
            <BuyDate>
                <date>20130509</date>
                <time/>
            </BuyDate>
            <SellDate>
                <date>20130511</date>
                <time/>
            </SellDate>
            <Destination>
                <Name/>
                <ZoneList/>
                <type>SIMPLE</type>
                <code>PMI</code>
            </Destination>
            <OccupancyList>
                <CarOccupancy>
                    <SpaceCount>1</SpaceCount>
                    <Occupancy/>
                    <ServiceOccupancy>
                        <AdultCount>1</AdultCount>
                        <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
                        <GuestList/>
                    </ServiceOccupancy>
                </CarOccupancy>
            </OccupancyList>
            <CarCodeList/>
            <CategoryList/>
            <BoardList/>
            <ShowDirectPayment/>
            <ShowNetPrice/>
            <Credentials>
                <User>xyz</User>
                <Password>xyz</Password>
            </Credentials>
            <sessionId>DummySessionId</sessionId>
        </CarValuedAvailRQ>
    </ns1:getCarValuedAvail>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Please refer to the XSL below -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

```
 <xsl:template match="//*[not(*)][contains('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',substring(local-name(),0,2))]">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected Output: As you can see all tags starting with small (non-capital) characters have been converted into attributes for their parent tags.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="Carz.com">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getCarValuedAvail sessionId="DummySessionId">
        <CarValuedAvailRQ>
            <PaginationData pageNumber="1" itemsPerPage=""/>
            <BuyDate date="20130509" time=""/>
            <SellDate date="20130511" time=""/>
            <Destination type="Simple" code="PMI">
                <Name/>
                <ZoneList/>
            </Destination>
            <OccupancyList>
                <CarOccupancy>
                    <SpaceCount>1</SpaceCount>
                    <Occupancy/>
                    <ServiceOccupancy>
                        <AdultCount>1</AdultCount>
                        <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
                        <GuestList/>
                    </ServiceOccupancy>
                </CarOccupancy>
            </OccupancyList>
            <CarCodeList/>
            <CategoryList/>
            <BoardList/>
            <ShowDirectPayment/>
            <ShowNetPrice/>
            <Credentials>
                <User>xyz</User>
                <Password>xyz</Password>
            </Credentials>
        </CarValuedAvailRQ>
    </ns1:getCarValuedAvail>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: So, what must be the exact wanted output from the transformation? Please, *edit* the question and provide this important information.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have edited the query to include expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a potential problem with your approach is that the specification requires that any attributes nodes in the result tree have to be created before any child nodes are created; if there is an attempt to create an attribute node after a child node has been created the processor either needs to signal an error or discard the attribute.

So basically you need to change the approach a bit to make sure you process any elements to be converted to attributes before other child elements. As you have tagged your question as XSLT 2.0 I post an XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[*[not(*) and matches(local-name(), '^[a-z]')]]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , *[not(*) and matches(local-name(), '^[a-z]')]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except *[not(*) and matches(local-name(), '^[a-z]')]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and matches(local-name(), '^[a-z]')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need to solve it with XSLT 1.0 then you can do that as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[*[not(*) and contains('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', substring(local-name(), 1, 1))]]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *[not(*) and contains('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', substring(local-name(), 1, 1))]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::*[not(*) 
                                        and 
                                        contains('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', substring(local-name(), 1, 1))])]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and contains('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', substring(local-name(), 1, 1))]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```